# AspectJ AfterReturning Advice Not Displaying Output in Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop

I'm trying to use Spring AOP with AspectJ to display an "After method" message using @AfterReturning advice. I've created an afterMethod aspect class, but the output isn't being displayed as expected.

Here is afterMethod.java

```
package AOP_Advice;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;

@Aspect
public class afterMethod {
    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* employee.employee..*.print(..))", returning = "returnValue")
    public void afterReturningAdvice(JoinPoint jp, Object returnValue) {
        System.out.println("After method: This is executed after the method.");
    }

}
```

employee.java (not too relative but just in case)

```
package employee;

public class employee {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int dob;

    // constructor
    public employee() {
    }

    public employee(String name, int age, int dob) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    // getter & setter
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(int dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "employee [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", dob=" + dob + "]";
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("name: " + this.name);
        System.out.println("Age: " + this.age);
        System.out.println("Day of birth: " + this.dob);
    }

    public void printThrowException() {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <!-- Enable AspectJ Proxy -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean id="emp1" class="employee.employee">
        <property name="name" value="Kelvin" />
        <property name="age" value="20" />
        <property name="dob" value="2003" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="emp2" class="employee.employee">
        <property name="name" value="Join" />
        <property name="age" value="25" />
        <property name="dob" value="1998" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.springAnnotationBasedAOP</groupId>
  <artifactId>springAnnotationBasedAOP</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>springAnnotationBasedAOP</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.25.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.25.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.25.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.20.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.20.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

and the main.java class

```
package main;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import employee.employee;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Using Annotations-based AOP
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");

        employee e1 = (employee)context.getBean("emp1");
        employee e2 = (employee)context.getBean("emp2");

        System.out.println("=====================");
        e1.print();
        System.out.println("=====================");
        e2.print();
        System.out.println("=====================");
    }
}
```

"What I'm trying to achieve is that after running the main class, it should first display the output of the print() method, and then immediately follow that by displaying the afterAdvice message as well, like this

```
=====================
name: Kelvin
Age: 20
Day of birth: 2003
After method: This is executed after the method.
=====================
name: Ryna
Age: 25
Day of birth: 1998
After method: This is executed after the method.
=====================
```

But the afterMethod seem like it not work, event the program can run
Is there anyone know this probleam and know how to fix it ?
thanks

Comment: of course that isn't going to run. Those pointcuts are only for after your methods returned a value, in your configuration, an Object. However, your methods are returntype void, so they don't return anything.

Comment: @Stultuske,your statement is incorrect. `@AfterReturning` is perfectly fine with `void` methods, the return value will simply be `null`.

Comment: Please react to my answer. It is not particularly polite to first ask a question and then neither to accept & upvote a correct answer nor to comment on what you dislike or do not understand about it. This way, you are not going to make lots of friends here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this to your configuration:

```xml
  <bean id="afterMethod" class="AOP_Advice.afterMethod"/>
```

And then fix your pointcut to either of these:

```java
execution(* employee.employee.print(..))
```

```java
execution(* employee..*.print(..))
```

I would also advise to learn about and adhere to Java package, class and method naming standards. Package names should only use lower-case characters, class names should use camel-case starting with a capital letter and method names camel-case starting with a lower-case letter. Especially horrible is method `main.main.main` (identical names for package, class and method).

My version of your application looks as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

  <bean id="loggingAspect" class="de.scrum_master.spring.q77329996.aop.LoggingAspect"/>
  <bean id="emp1" class="de.scrum_master.spring.q77329996.entity.Employee">
    <property name="name" value="Kelvin"/>
    <property name="age" value="20"/>
    <property name="dob" value="2003"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="emp2" class="de.scrum_master.spring.q77329996.entity.Employee">
    <property name="name" value="Join"/>
    <property name="age" value="25"/>
    <property name="dob" value="1998"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q77329996.entity;

public class Employee {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private int dob;

  public Employee(String name, int age, int dob) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.dob = dob;
  }

  public Employee() {}

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  public int getDob() {
    return dob;
  }

  public void setDob(int dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "employee [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", dob=" + dob + "]";
  }

  public void print() {
    System.out.println("name: " + this.name);
    System.out.println("Age: " + this.age);
    System.out.println("Day of birth: " + this.dob);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q77329996.aop;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;

@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
  @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* de.scrum_master.spring.q77329996.entity.Employee.print(..))", returning = "returnValue")
  public void interceptPrint(JoinPoint jp, Object returnValue) {
    System.out.println(jp + " -> " + returnValue);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q77329996.application;

import de.scrum_master.spring.q77329996.entity.Employee;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-config-q77329996.xml");
    Employee e1 = (Employee) context.getBean("emp1");
    Employee e2 = (Employee) context.getBean("emp2");
    System.out.println("=====================");
    e1.print();
    System.out.println("=====================");
    e2.print();
    System.out.println("=====================");
  }
}
```

Console log:

```
=====================
name: Kelvin
Age: 20
Day of birth: 2003
execution(void de.scrum_master.spring.q77329996.entity.Employee.print()) -> null
=====================
name: Join
Age: 25
Day of birth: 1998
execution(void de.scrum_master.spring.q77329996.entity.Employee.print()) -> null
=====================
```